# How to install pymorph on windows?

Tags: python

I am very new to python so sorry if this is a trivial question. I am developing on windows and I want to install the following library [pymorph](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pymorph)

I know it can be installed on linux but how to install it on windows enviroment ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Download the package. Extract the package, cd to the folder (make sure setup.py is in the folder) and run `python setup.py install` from your cmd while in said folder.

Comment: I did download and extract and tried this from the windows command line but it will give that python is an invalid command.

Comment: do you have python installed? go through this: http://docs.python.org/faq/windows.html

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 main ways to install a python dependency.

**First method**

You can install pymorph (and almost all python dependencies) with the `easy_install` software. You can retrieve it [here](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#downloads).

Example :

Run the `setuptools-0.6c11.win32-py2.7.exe` if you are using python version 2.7.

After that, you have the `easy_install` executable.

To install pymorph (in a shell, using cmd.exe) :

```
easy_install-2.7 pymorph
```

Don't forget to adapt the name of the easy_install executable with the good python version.

The advantage of this method is that it uses the Python Package Index :

According to Wikipedia :

> The Python Package Index or PyPI is the official third-party software repository for the Python programming language. Python developers intend of it to be a comprehensive catalog of all open source Python packages.[1](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#downloads) It is analogous to CPAN, the repository for Perl. Package managers such as EasyInstall, pip and PyPM use PyPI as the default source for packages and their dependencies.

---

**Second method**

In a shell, using the cmd.exe, go to the pymorph folder. After that, always in your shell :

```
python setup.py install
```

In a same way, python executable name can depend of the version of python. Example :

**python2.7** for python version 2.7